# Get tallest building name and height

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a project where I created a nested data structure to find the tallest building name and height.

This is the data:

```
let buildings =[
    {
        name: "Burj Khalifa",
        height: 828
    },
    {
        name: "Shanghai Tower",
        height: 632
    },
    {
        name: "Lotte Tower",
        height: 555
    },
    {
        name: "CTF Finance Centre",
        height: 803
    }
];
```

And this is the solution:

```
function getTallestBuilding() {
    let height = 0;
    let buildingName = "";
    for (let building = 0; building < buildings.length; building++) {
        height = Math.max.apply(Math, buildings.map(function (o) {return o.height;
        }));
        buildingName = buildings[building].buildingName;
    }
    console.log("The tallest building's height is " + height + " and the name is " + buildingName);
}
```

I can only get the height of the building but the name is always the last one which is CTF Finance Centre. It should print out as:

`The tallest building's height is 828 and the name is Burj Khalifa`

Comment: You're looping over every element in the array, so when the loop is done, the `name` is the last one in the loop.

Comment: Why not just sort the array and then grab the first/last one (depending on sort direction) to get the tallest?

Comment: @Taplar you could do that, but it would be less efficient because that is O(n log(n)) where you could do it in O(n) like the OP is doing.

Comment: Also, you are calculating the `max` height from the array 4 times!  You are doing each iteration in your loop.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel not arguing statistics, but given 4 elements, or with the actual data, does it actually matter?

Comment: @Taplar don't know what the full data set might be like, so could be a moot point and could not be.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let buildings =[
{
    name: "Burj Khalifa",
    height: 828
},
{
    name: "Shanghai Tower",
    height: 632
},
{
    name: "Lotte Tower",
    height: 555
},
{
    name: "CTF Finance Centre",
    height: 803
}
];

const tallestObj = buildings.reduce((a,b)=>a.height > b.height ? a : b);
console.info(`The tallest building's height is ${tallestObj.height} and the name is ${tallestObj.name}`);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I'm curious but what does a and b does?

Comment: @reiko Added links. It's just comparing two buildings. `a` is a building and `b` is a building.